# Dynamic Memory Allocation in C not working

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to make a game that requires dynamically sized arrays in C but my code isn't working even though identical code works in another one of my programs.

Here are my `#includes`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "SwinGame.h" //API for graphics, physics etc
#include <math.h>
```

Here are my `typedefs` for the relevant `structs` used:

```
typedef struct position_data
{
  double x;
  double y;
} position_data;

typedef enum enemy_type_data {CIRCLE, TRIANGLE, SQUARE} enemy_type_data;

typedef struct enemy_data
{
  position_data location;
  enemy_type_data type;
  bitmap bmp;
  double health;
  double speed;
  int path_to;
} enemy_data;

typedef struct enemy_data_array
{
  int size;
  enemy_data *data;
} enemy_data_array;
```

Here is the function to add an element to the array:

```
void add_enemy(enemy_data_array *enemies)
{
  enemy_data *new_array;
  enemies->size++;
  new_array = (enemy_data *)realloc(enemies->data, sizeof(enemy_data) * enemies->size);
  if (new_array) //if realloc fails (ie out of memory) it will return null
  {
    enemies->data = new_array;
    // enemies->data[enemies->size - 1] = read_enemy_data();
    printf("Enemy added successfully!\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("FAILED. Out of Memory!\n");
    enemies->size--;
  }
}
```

And here is my function call and variable declaration in the main procedure:

```
int main()
{
  path_data my_path[41];
  enemy_data_array enemies;
  enemies.size = 0;
  add_enemy(&enemies);
}
```

Why isn't this working?

Comment: the posted code is missing some key details, like the `#include` statements and the definition of `bitmap` and `position_data`.   
When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. 
(for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-std=gnu99 -Wconversion` )

Comment: will edit now to add those details. Thanks @user3629249

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You invoked *undefined behavior* by passing indeterminate value `enemies->data` in uninitialized variable having automatic storage duration. Initialize it before using `add_enemy()`.

```
int main()
{
  path_data my_path[41];
  enemy_data_array enemies;
  enemies.size = 0;
  enemies.data = 0; /* add this line */
  add_enemy(&enemies);
}
```

`0` is a *null pointer constant* and can safely be converted to pointer `NULL`. Unlike `NULL`, `0` will work without including any headers. Of course you can use `enemies.data = NULL;` with proper header included.

Comment: In this case, passing an automatic struct that had at least one member initialized or assigned to is not undefined behavior. Undefined behavior occurs when realloc is called on a pointer that has an indeterminate value.

Answer (score 3):

[@2501's explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38288395/dynamic-memory-allocation-in-c-not-working/38288451#comment63995249_38288416) is completely correct. Another solution is to change your implementation of `add_enemy()` to something like this:

```
void add_enemy(enemy_data_array *enemies)
{
  enemy_data *new_array;

  // check if size was non-zero
  if (enemies->size++)
  {
    new_array = (enemy_data *)realloc(enemies->data, sizeof(enemy_data) * enemies->size);
  }
  // start new allocation
  else
  {
    new_array = (enemy_data *)alloc(sizeof(enemy_data) * enemies->size);
  }

  if (new_array) //if (re)alloc fails (ie out of memory) it will return null
  {
    enemies->data = new_array;
    // enemies->data[enemies->size - 1] = read_enemy_data();
    printf("Enemy added successfully!\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("FAILED. Out of Memory!\n");
    enemies->size--;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If fails because you haven't cleared the content of "enemies".   Since it is a stack variable, it will contain whatever garbage data is on the stack.

set enemies.data to NULL in the main function and try it again.